# Text formatting in ggplot's annotate

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggtext

Is it possible to annotate with html code? I'm trying to color only a few words and not the entire text.

```r
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 4.0.2

mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = hp, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  annotate(geom = "text", label = "I'm <span style='color: red;'>red</span> \n and i'm <span style='color: orange;'>orange</span>",
           x = 250, y = 25)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-08-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use package 'ggtext'. It is quite new. The only change needed for your example is to replace the geom: using `"richtext"` instead of `"text"`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggtext)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 4.0.2

mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = hp, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  annotate(geom = "richtext", label = "I'm <span style='color: red;'>red</span> \n and i'm <span style='color: orange;'>orange</span>",
           x = 250, y = 25)
```

[image]

It is possible to use `fill = NA` to remove the background. To remove the border line `label.color = NA` can be used.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggtext)

mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = hp, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  annotate(geom = "richtext", label = "I'm <span style='color: red;'>red</span>\n and i'm <span style='color: orange;'>orange</span>",
           x = 250, y = 25, fill = NA, label.color = NA)
```

[image]

Comment: You should use the <br> tag instead of \n to achieve the desired output. @alberson-miranda

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to change the fill of only part of the text? I tried doing something like `<span style='background-color:#fff'>`, but it did not work.